# Apache Kafka: KafkaProducerActor throws exception ASk timeout.

Tags: scala, akka, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using cake solution [Akka client for scala and Kafka](https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client/wiki/Akka%20Integration). While I am creating a `KafkaProducerActor` actor and trying to send message using `ask` pattern and return future and perform some operations, but every time, I am facing `ask` timeout exception. Below is my code:

```
class SimpleAkkaProducer (config: Config, system: ActorSystem) {

  private val producerConf = KafkaProducer.
    Conf(config,
      keySerializer = new StringSerializer,
      valueSerializer = new StringSerializer)

  val actorRef = system.actorOf(KafkaProducerActor.props(producerConf))

  def sendMessageWayOne(record: ProducerRecords[String, String]) = {
    actorRef ! record
  }

  def sendMessageWayTwo(record: ProducerRecords[String, String]) = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(100.seconds)
    val future = (actorRef ? record).mapTo[String]
    future onComplete  {
      case Success(data) => println(s" >>>>>>>>>>>> ${data}")
      case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
    }
  }
}

object SimpleAkkaProducer {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("KafkaProducerActor")
    val config = ConfigFactory.defaultApplication()
    val simpleAkkaProducer = new SimpleAkkaProducer(config, system)

    val topic = config.getString("akka.topic")
    val messageOne = ProducerRecords.fromKeyValues[String, String](topic,
      Seq((Some("Topics"), "First Message")), None, None)

    simpleAkkaProducer.sendMessageWayOne(messageOne)
    simpleAkkaProducer.sendMessageWayTwo(messageOne)
  }
}
```

Following is exception :

```
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [Actor[akka://KafkaProducerActor/user/$a#-1520717141]] after [100000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "cakesolutions.kafka.akka.ProducerRecords".
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$.$anonfun$apply$1(AskSupport.scala:604)
    at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$4.run(Scheduler.scala:126)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:864)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor.execute$(BatchingExecutor.scala:103)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:862)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskHolder.executeTask(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:329)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.executeBucket$1(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:280)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.nextTick(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:284)
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$$anon$4.run(LightArrayRevolverScheduler.scala:236)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Add the definition of `KafkaProducerActor`.

Comment: `KafkaProducerActor` is design by api and implementation as like https://github.com/cakesolutions/scala-kafka-client/blob/1cbeccbb183ca06585f4b9fb1e366048e993ac51/akka/src/main/scala/cakesolutions/kafka/akka/KafkaProducerActor.scala

Comment: Hey @YuvalItzchakov have you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The producer actor only responds to the sender, if you specify the `successResponse` and `failureResponse` values in the `ProducerRecords` to be something other than `None`. The `successResponse` value is sent back to the sender when the Kafka write succeeds, and `failureResponse` value is sent back when the Kafka write fails.

Example:

```
val record = ProducerRecords.fromKeyValues[String, String](
  topic = topic,
  keyValues = Seq((Some("Topics"), "First Message")),
  successResponse = Some("success"),
  failureResponse = Some("failure")
)

val future = (actorRef ? record).mapTo[String]
future onComplete  {
  case Success("success") => println("Send succeeded!")
  case Success("failure") => println("Send failed!")
  case Success(data) => println(s"Send result: $data")
  case Failure(ex) => ex.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: Okay @Jaakko, this makes sense, This is working, But still how can we get `RrecordMetaData` after send the message ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to get the `RecordMetaData` with the current version of the producer actor. Patches and suggestions are welcome on the project page. :)